# How to require normal disconnect on two BC04-B Bluetooth Module in Arduino?

Tags: module, arduino, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, at-command

I use two Arduino board (One Uno and One **Mega2560**) and two **BC04-B** bluetooth Module. 
And I use AT command with SoftwareSerial library to connect them (One master and One slave). 
And now I want to disconnect them, but if they are connected, I can't send AT command anymore. 
As now I only find the way is cutoff **BC04-B** Module's power source to disconnect them. 
Is possible to use arduino code or another way to normal disconnect them?

Here is arduino code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial BT(10, 9);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  BT.begin(9600);
  BT.write("AT+CONNECT98,d3,32,30,4d,83");
} 

void loop() {
  
}
```

And serial monitor :

```
16:29:51.309 -> +CONNECTING>>98:d3:32:30:4d:83
16:29:51.344 -> OK
16:29:54.569 -> +CONNECTED
```

Comment: Post your code that you tried

Comment: So you can't send any commands?

Comment: If I send commands after they connected, master BT module will send message to slave BT module.
AT command will not working.

Comment: And also I been checked BC04-B's datasheet.
Link:http://www.suptronics.com/downloads/BC04-B_AT%20Command.pdf
There is no AT command about request disconnect.

Comment: Replace those modules with HM-10 or HM-16(recommended). If you don't want to replace, here is datasheet http://www.suptronics.com/downloads/BC04-B_AT%20Command.pdf
`AT+DISC:SUCCESS` should disconnect modules

Comment: @Pararera Actually I tried AT command about "AT+DISC",but it still not working. I'll try HM-10 module,that look like useful and easy to use. Thank you for your answer.